# Minimum number from Text Boxes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create simple program that lets user write 1-5 numbers and I want the program to tell him what the lowest number is. But I don't know how to make this work from Text Boxes.

[image]

User can chose the amount of numbers via radio buttons and then write down the numbers in Tex Boxes. Upon clicking on Go I want the program to tell what the lowest number is.

Comment: What is your programming language? Do you have a code snippet to share?

Answer (score 2):

Every text box will have a properties window wherein you can give it a "name".

This name property will let you refer that textbox while coding.

Then to get its value u need to use "name.value" in your code.This works in most programming and scripting languages.It would help if u specify what language you are using.

For eg, if you name your text box as "num1" (without quotes)

Then in code use it as:

```
num1.value
```

**Edited after OP comments:**

In case of C# use

```
num1.Text
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that - I use C#

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of the TextBox objects - by default it is TextBox1, TextBox2 ...

If you didn't change the names the code should look like that:

```
int textBox1Value;
if (Int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out textBox1Value))
{
   // Success - that means that the input is a valid integer
   Console.WriteLine("TextBox1 Value: {0}", textBox1Value);
}
```

I would suggest you to replace your text boxes to NumericUpDown controls which validates that your input is an integer and then you can just use:

```
int numericUpDown1Value = NumericUpDown1.Value;
```